# Uploading multiple images with React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I would like to upload multiple images first by previewing them then submitting to send them off. I have encountered this: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null`. It also only lets me upload just one image.

- I have created `files: []` as means to mount the images for review before submitting.
- Tried creating an interface `files: File[] = file` then declaring it in state but get a different error that `file does not exist on type {}`

```
import * as React from "react"

class ImageUpload extends React.Component {
  state: {
    files: []
  }

  fileSelectedHandler = (file: any) => {
    let addedFiles = this.state.files.concat(file)
    this.setState({ files: addedFiles })
    console.log("upload file " + file.name)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      < form >
        <div>
          <h2>Upload images</h2>
        </div>
        <h3>Images</h3>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.fileSelectedHandler} />
      </form>
    )
  }
}

export default ImageUpload
```

I expect it to allow me to select multiple images and store them in the array before sending them off as a batch. Is this even the right way to do it? Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. In order to fix the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of null.` you need to change the `state` declaration

```
state = {
   files: []
}
```

2. If you want to have the opportunity to select multiple files you can use `multiple` option

```
<input type="file" multiple onChange={this.fileSelectedHandler} />
```

Or if you want to select image one by one, your implementation should work, just fix the `state` declaration and use `e.target.files` to get selected file

```js
class ImageUpload extends React.Component {
  state = {
    files: []
  }

  fileSelectedHandler = (e) => {
    this.setState({ files: [...this.state.files, ...e.target.files] })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <div><h2>Upload images</h2></div>
        <h3>Images</h3>
        <input type="file" multiple onChange={this.fileSelectedHandler} />
      </form>
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<ImageUpload />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you,this works quite well. Would also like to point out the error I was getting was because I used an : instead of = when declaring my state. Woops.

Answer (score 2):

Updated Answer with Typescript as a sperate componnent

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const UploadAndDisplayImage = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([] as any);
  const [imageURLS, setImageURLs] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (images.length < 1) return;
    const newImageUrls: any = [];
    images.forEach((image:any) => newImageUrls.push(URL.createObjectURL(image)));
    setImageURLs(newImageUrls);
  }, [images]);

  function onImageChange(e: any) {
    setImages([...e.target.files]);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <input type="file" multiple accept="image/*" onChange={onImageChange} />
      {imageURLS.map((imageSrc) => (
        <img src={imageSrc} alt="not fount" width={"250px"} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default UploadAndDisplayImage;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Handle Form**
Initial data:

```
const initialProducts = {
name: "",   
featured_image: "", //for single image
slider_images: [], // (array of strings)   
};
```

useState

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState(initialProducts);
```

Function: Handle Input Fields

```
const handleInput = (e) => {
let updateValues = { ...products };
updateValues[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
setProducts(updateValues);
console.log("Update input values", updateValues);
};
```

Function: Handle Multiple Images

```
 const handleSliderImages = (e) => {
  if (e.target.files) {
  setProducts({ ...products, slider_images: [...e.target.files] });
  }
  console.log("Update slider images", products);
};
```

FormGroup for Input Fields

```
<FormGroup className="my-3">
  <Label for="name">Name</Label>
   <Field
    name="name"
    id="name"
    onChange={handleInput}
    value={products.name}
   />
</FormGroup>
```

FormGroup for single Image

```
 <FormGroup className="my-3">
  <Label for="featured_image">Featured Image</Label>
  <CustomInput
   type="file"
   id="featured_image"
   name="featured_image"
   onChange={handleInput}
   value={products.featured_image}                  
  />               
 </FormGroup>
```

FormGroup for Multiple Images

```
<FormGroup className="my-3">
 <Label for="slider_images">Slider Images</Label>
 <CustomInput
 multiple
 type="file"
 id="slider_images"
 name="slider_images"
 onChange={handleSliderImages}
 />                
</FormGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by multiple input fields. You are able to track the input field used to upload the file using their unique "ID". Please take a look to the code that I shared.

[Input field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrUQQ.png)

[onChange handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8psa.png)

[file handler based on id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ02v.png)

Answer (score 0):

[image: create states(the images state u can use in api if you wanna send those images to api]

[image: handle images with createProductImageChange]

[image: add input with multiple attribute and use imagesPreviewState for whoweing on the screen]

It is simple You should follow the steps which i wrote and i hope this will help

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).